# VBA excel add new worksheet and deleted the original

Tags: vba

I would like to create a button that add a new worksheet and extract the data from worksheet ("data") to a new worksheet ("report")

However, if i click the button one more time it will come up an error "worksheet name duplicated"

Therefore i would like to add a function in my original code that if the worksheet name "report"
exist then delete it else generate the report.

But i m not sure how to modify it in my original code 
 And i m not sure do i need a new for each loop

```
Private Sub CommandButton3_Click()

 Dim rng As Range
 Dim ss As Range, cel As Range
Dim yesno As Range
Dim lastrow As Long    
 //looking for the last row    of      the data
 Dim tws As Worksheet
 Dim tlr, i&

 Set wks = Sheets("Data")
 With wks
  lastrow = .Range("A3").End(xlDown).Row

   Set yesno = .Range("AX3:AX" & lastrow)
 Set tws =   Worksheets.Add(after:=
 Sheets(Worksheets.Count))
 tws.Name = ("report")
 //fetch the first row as the title 
 Set rng = Union(.Range("B1"),
     .Range("F1"),                                           
    .Range("G1"),
   .Range("H1"),
    .Range("N1"),.Range(".O1"), .Range("Q1"), 
    .Range("U1"),.Range("W1"))
   rng.Copy tws.Range("A1")

 //fetec the data with condition
 For Each ss In yesno
 If LCase(ss.Cells.Value) = "Yes" And 
  LCase(ss.Cells.Offset(0, -31).Value) = "trigger"      
   And
   LCase(ss.Cells.Offset(0, -47).Value) = "trigger"        
    Then
    Set rng = Union(.Range("B" & ss.Row),    
    .Range("F" & ss.Row),
  .Range("G" & ss.Row), .Range("H" & ss.Row),    
   .Range("N" & ss.Row),
  .Range("O"&   ss.Row), .Range("Q" & ss.Row),   
   .Range("U" & ss.Row),
    .Range("W" & ss.Row))
     tlr = tws.Range("A" &     
   tws.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Row
    rng.Copy tws.Cells(tlr, "A")
    ElseIf LCase(ss.Cells.Value) = "No" Then
   End If
    Next

   End With









     End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Try adding this before the line that adds the new workbook.

On Error Resume Next

Set tws = Sheets("Report")

On Error Goto 0

If Not tws Is Nothing Then 
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    tws.Delete
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True 
End If